# Prometheus storage.tsdb.retention vs storage.local.retention?

Tags: prometheus

Trying to have my retention period of about 30d, and looking at configs, I am seeing 2 different flags that seem to do the same thing(ish).

What is the difference between `storage.tsdb.retention` and `storage.local.retention`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--storage.tsdb.retention` is for Prometheus 2.x, `-storage.local.retention` is for Prometheus 1.x.